# Google Sheets reference to other sheets using indirect formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following formula in Excel which is successfully calculating the count of Calls (Sheet names are Call 1 through Call 23) that fall within the specified range in this formula (Start date is in cell C1 and End Date is in Cell D1).

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&"Call "&ROW($1:$23)&"'"&"!$B$2"), ">="&$C$1, INDIRECT("'"&"Call "&ROW($1:$23)&"'"&"!$B$2"), "<="&$D$1))
```

This formula is working fine in Excel. But when i use this same formula in google sheet with same data sheets, it does not give me the right result. In excel the result is for example 23, but in google sheets, the result is always 1 even when more than 1 calls fall within that date range. please help me what is the difference between using this formula with excel and google sheets?
Link to the actual google sheet is this:
[My Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s4CmM5Gj7udTUqCVPaJE3uVS0DbIWcqCHnTGlSYk7Rc/edit#gid=1380646932)

I need to make smart formulas like the one i mentioned above in cells E3 and F3 of Call Tracking Sheet.

Comment: First, you already askes same question yesterday. Second, you shared sheet is with restricted access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indirect formula in google sheet - Issue using this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653942/indirect-formula-in-google-sheet-issue-using-this-formula)

Comment: @user11222393 yes i asked same question but there was not answer to that question. today i put that again with the link to my google sheet.
I have given full editing rights in my google sheet now. Thanks for your time dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach for the `total calls` value from all the existing `18` tabs:*

```js
=reduce(,index("Call "&sequence(18)),lambda(a,c,a+isbetween(iferror(indirect(c&"!B2")),C1,D1)))
```

[image]